# Contents of following page visible on previous page after animation

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIPageViewController` with vertical scrolling which basically works fine. However, I encountered a minor problem which I haven't been able to fix yet:

Each page in the `UIPageViewController` is supposed to "reset" the page (make elements which have been animated out of the page return to it, so to say animating them back in) when the transition to a page `didFinishAnimating` and was thus completed:

```
internal func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```

The problem is that some UI elements (i.e. UIView, UILabel and UIButton) which have been animated vertically up outside the page are now visible on the previous page (which looks quite ugly since one always sees how the elements are going back down to the following page animatedly when one goes back to previous page). The reason I want to animate the "resetting" is that the function (see above) is even called when not a new page is being shown (e.g. the user scrolls down just a bit and consequently sees just a bit of the next page and then lifts his finger; the page he was on already will trigger the function meaning it tries to reset and I didn't want to just directly (without animations) set it to its new position since that looks even uglier).

Consequently, there would be two ways to solve this problem:

A function like the one above which would also take the change of the page into consideration (is there one in swift?) or a way not to let contents of the following page be over the previous one if these have been animated as previously described, up and out of the page (is there a way to hide them?).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a clean way myself (below) when thinking about implementing a not so clean way, namely to detect a change in page.

```
internal func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if completed {
        //calling my reset function
    }
}
```

`if completed` does the trick which I perceive as rather clean compared to indexing the pages to detect a change. Consequently, I reset it without any animations now... (see question, paragraph after function)